# UICollectionView: How to get item size for a specific item after setting them in delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I am fiddling with the new UICollectionView and the UICollectionViewLayout classes. I have created a custom layout, subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

My cell sizes are changing dynamically and I set the item sizes using the delegate method below

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %d", indexPath.row);
      return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}
```

Now, under the prepareLayout method of my custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout class, I need to access these size variables so that I can make calculations how to place them and cache them for layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath.

However, I can't seem to find any property under UICollectionView or UICollectionViewFlowLayout to reach the custom item sizes I set in the delegate method.

Comment: you can call the delegate method by yourself.

Comment: can't do that, it Xcode doesn't validate this: 

CGSize size =  [self.collectionView sizeForItemAtIndexPath:   [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];

Comment: you have to call `[self collectionView:self.collectionView layout:self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

Comment: Getting this error: No visible @interface for 'SECollectionViewCustomLayout' declares the selector 'collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:'

Comment: oh sorry u are in the Layout Class. Than you have to call `[self.collectionView.delegate collectionView:self.collectionView layout:self sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

Comment: Still no lock. Says: No known instance method for selector 'collectionView:layout:'. The problem is that collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: is under UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. Check the url here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:

Comment: @SarpErdag this works when you cast the delegate like: `[(id<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>)self.collectionView.delegate collectionView: self.collectionView layout: self referenceSizeForHeaderInSection: section];`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it myself.

Implement the custom class like without omitting `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
@interface SECollectionViewCustomLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
                                          <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

and then you can call

```
CGSize size = [self collectionView:self.collectionView 
                            layout:self 
            sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: -1 Making the layout its own delegate is an odd pattern to follow. Even if you really do want to do this, you should get the size information by calling through `self.collectionView.delegate` rather than assuming that `self` will always be the delegate. What if you later decide a different object should be the delegate? Chances are you'll end up with this bit of code hanging around returning a different size to the actual delegate. Even removing conformance to the delegate protocol will not result in a compiler warning, as `self` implements the method anyway.

Comment: I'm using Swift not ObjC but why not just have your delegate object conform to BOTH `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`? Then you can just do something like if let d = self.collectionView?.delegate as? `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in the layout class and it works like a charm

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the various `UICollectionView...` header files, and watching the [WWDC 2012 Session 219 - Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) video (from about 6:50 onwards), it seems the extensible delegate pattern takes advantage of dynamic typing to ensure the layout can properly access its extended delegate methods.

### In short...

1. If you define a custom layout with its own delegate, define that delegate protocol in the layout's header file.
2. Your delegate object (typically the `UI(Collection)ViewController` that manages the collection view) should declare itself to support this custom protocol.

   - *In the case that your layout is just a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or subclass thereof, this just means declaring conformance to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.*
   - *Feel free to do this in your class extension in the `.m` file if you'd rather not `#import` the layout header into the delegate's interface.*
3. To access the delegate methods from the layout, call through to the collection view's delegate.

   - *Use the layout's `collectionView` property, and **cast the delegate to an object conforming to the required protocol** to convince the compiler.*
   - *Don't forget to check that the delegate `respondsToSelector:` as usual prior to calling optional delegate methods. In fact, if you like, there's no harm in doing this for all methods, as the typecasting means there is no runtime guarantee the delegate will even implement the required methods.*

### In code...

So if you implement a custom layout that requires a delegate for some of its information, your header might look something like this:

```
@protocol CollectionViewDelegateCustomLayout <UICollectionViewDelegate>
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
shouldDoSomethingMindblowingAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@interface CustomLayout : UICollectionViewLayout
// ...
@end
```

Your delegate declares conformance (I've done so in the implementation file here):

```
#import "CustomLayout.h"

@interface MyCollectionViewController () <CollectionViewDelegateCustomLayout>
@end

@implementation
// ...
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
shouldDoSomethingMindblowingAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self canDoSomethingMindblowing];
}
// ...
@end
```

And in your layout's implementation, you access the method like this:

```
BOOL blowMind;
if ([self.collectionView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selecor(collectionView:layout:shouldDoSomethingMindblowingAtIndexPath:)]) {
    blowMind = [(id<CollectionViewDelegateCustomLayout>)self.collectionView.delegate collectionView:self.collectionView
                                                                                             layout:self
                                                            shouldDoSomethingMindblowingAtIndexPath:indexPath];
} else {
    // Perhaps the layout also has a property for this, if the delegate
    // doesn't support dynamic layout properties...?
    // blowMind = self.blowMind;
}
```

Note that it's safe to typecast here, as we're checking the delegate responds to that method beforehand anyway.

### The evidence...

It's only speculation, but I suspect it is how Apple manages the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

- There is no `delegate` property on the flow layout, so calls must go via the collection view's delegate.
- `UICollectionViewController` does not publicly conform to extended flow layout delegate (and I doubt it does so in another private header).
- `UICollectionView`'s `delegate` property only declares conformance to the 'base' `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol. Again, I doubt there is a private subclass/category of `UICollectionView` in use by the flow layout to prevent the need for typecasting. To add further weight to this point, Apple discourages subclassing `UICollectionView` at all in the docs ([Collection View Programming Guide for iOS: Creating Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW8)):

> Avoid subclassing UICollectionView. The collection view has little or no appearance of its own. Instead, it pulls all of its views from your data source object and all of the layout-related information from the layout object.

So there we go. Not complicated, but worth knowing how to do it paradigm-friendly way.

Answer (score 8):

There is a swift version:

```
self.collectionView(self.collectionView, layout: self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [UICollectionView-FlowLayout](https://github.com/charlieelliott/UICollectionView-FlowLayout) on GitHub. Same idea, this just makes accessing the extended delegate methods of flowLayout a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

For the later readers, IOS 7 has UICollectionViewFlowLayout which has defined it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case everything about layout, cell layout etc. is being defined inside nib for UIViewController and separate nib for UICollectionViewCell. `MyCollectionViewCell` contains `UIImageView` with autolayout to cell with padding/margins but square-shaped.

I need round icons instead squared but don't want to take care which nib I use for iPhone or for iPad (I have separate nibs for devices and for orientation as well).

I don't want to implement `@selector(collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` into my view controller.

So, inside `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` 
I can just use

```
CGSize size = cell.imageView.bounds.size;
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = size.height/2.0;
```

Because `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` call before `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and layout done.

You can check round avatars on the bottom

[image]